# Java regex and replaceAll to extract strings into objects

Tags: java, performance, strings, regex, android

I have this method that creates book objects. I pass a list of strings (size 60000+) that contain the information of the book, the function then goes and extracts the information makes the book object and adds to a global list.

This solution works, but is not memory that efficient and slow due to the replacements and regex that happen each loop and strings being made. So, can I make improvements to my regex and is there a better way perform many replacements per loop

```java
    private static void defineBooks(List<String> paragraphs) {
    // Pattern id = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]\\d+");
    Pattern title = Pattern.compile("[\\S\\s]+");
    Pattern author = Pattern.compile(", by(.*)(?=\\s*)");
    Pattern subtitle = Pattern.compile("\\[Subtitle: [^\\[\\]]+]");
    Pattern language = Pattern.compile("\\[Language: [^\\[\\]]+]");
    Pattern contents = Pattern.compile("\\[Contents: [^\\[\\]]+]");
    Pattern tempx = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,5}$");
    Pattern tempy = Pattern.compile("^\\d{1,5}|\\d{1,5}[A-Z]?\\s?$");
    Pattern i = Pattern.compile("^, by ");
    Pattern j = Pattern.compile("\\s+(?<= )\\d+(\\w)?$|(?<= )\\d+(\\w)?\\s+$|(?<=\\D)\\d+(\\w)?$");

    for (int i1 = 0, paragraphsSize = paragraphs.size(); i1 < paragraphsSize; i1++) {
        String para = paragraphs.get(i1);
        Matcher mid = tempx.matcher(para.replaceAll("\n.+", ""));
        Matcher midy = tempy.matcher(para.replaceAll("\n.+", ""));
        Matcher mtitle = title.matcher(para);
        Matcher mauthor = author.matcher(para);
        Matcher msubtitle = subtitle.matcher(para);
        Matcher mlanguage = language.matcher(para);
        Matcher mcontents = contents.matcher(para);

        Book book = new Book();

        Matcher temp = Pattern.compile("@\\d{1,5}[A-Z]?@?")
                .matcher(para.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", "@"));

        if (temp.find()) {
            book.setId(temp.group().replaceAll("@", ""));
        } else if (mid.find()) {
            book.setId(mid.group().trim());
        } else if (midy.find()) {
            book.setId(midy.group().trim());
        }
        if (mtitle.find()) {
            book.setTitle(para.replaceAll("\\[[^\\[]+(?:])", "")
                    .replaceAll("(Passed | by|, by).*+", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s{2,}\\d{1,5}(\\s)?", "")
                    .replaceAll("\n", " ")
                    .replaceAll(",$", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim());
        }
        if (mauthor.find()) {
            String bauthor = i.matcher(mauthor.group()).replaceAll("");
            book.setAuthor(j.matcher(bauthor).replaceAll(""));
        }
        if (msubtitle.find()) {
            book.setSubtitle(msubtitle.group()
                    .replaceAll("\\[Subtitle: ", "")
                    .replaceAll("]", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " "));
        } else {
            book.setSubtitle("");
        }
        if (mcontents.find()) {
            book.setContents(mcontents.group()
                    .replaceAll("\\[Contents: ", "")
                    .replaceAll("]", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " "));
        } else {
            book.setContents("");
        }
        if (mlanguage.find()) {
            book.setLanguage(mlanguage.group()
                    .replaceAll("\\[Language: ", "")
                    .replaceAll("]", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " "));
        } else {
            book.setLanguage("English");
        }

        if (!Objects.equals(book.getId(), "")) {
            books.add(book);
        }
    }
```

**Book**

````java
public class Book {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String subtitle;
    private String contents;
    private String language;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    public void setContents(String contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
    }

    public String getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed my code to use substring and indexOf to extract the text from each string, which has resulted in a 30% performance increase. The memory usage is still on the high end but the method is on its own thread so there is no noticeable performance drop when the gc runs.

**Before (With subtitle example)**

```
private static void defineBooks(List<String> paragraphs) {
    ...
Pattern subtitle = Pattern.compile("\\[Subtitle: [^\\[\\]]+]");
    ...
for (int i1 = 0, paragraphsSize = paragraphs.size(); i1 < paragraphsSize; i1++) {
    ...
    Matcher msubtitle = subtitle.matcher(para);
    //...

    Book book = new Book();

    ... 
    //Old subtitle code

    if (msubtitle.find()) {
        book.setSubtitle(msubtitle.group()
                .replaceAll("\\[Subtitle: ", "")
                .replaceAll("]", "")
                .replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " "));
    } else {
        book.setSubtitle("");
    }

    ...

    if (!Objects.equals(book.getId(), "")) {
        books.add(book);
    }
}
```

**After (along with Doi9t's answer)**

```
private static void defineBooks(List<String> paragraphs) {
    for (String para : paragraphs) {
        ...
        Book book = new Book();
        ...
        String subtitle = fastSubtitle(para);
        book.setSubtitle(subtitle);
        ...
        if (!Objects.equals(book.getId(), "")) {
            books.add(book);
        }
    }
}


private static String fastSubtitle(String para) {
    if (para.contains("[Subtitle:")) {
        try {
            return para.substring(para.indexOf("[Subtitle:") + 10, para.indexOf("]", para.indexOf("Subtitle:")));
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            try {
                return para.substring(para.indexOf("[Language:") + 10, para.indexOf("[") - 1);
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ey) {
                return para.substring(para.indexOf("[Language:") + 10, para.length() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

I am aware that I could use an if statements in the subtitle method but this does the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [Flyweight Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) if you have duplicates in the data. This pattern uses a cache to prevent the recalculation of similar objects.

Here is some general recommendation for your code; those changes won’t help for the performance issue, but will help when reading the code and make it shorter.

1) Extract the `java.util.regex.Pattern#compile(java.lang.String)` into constants; so it will be loaded only once per [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html), instead of each time you call the function.

```java
public static final Pattern TITLE = Pattern.compile("[\\S\\s]+");
public static final Pattern AUTHOR = Pattern.compile(", by(.*)(?=\\s*)");
public static final Pattern SUBTITLE = Pattern.compile("\\[Subtitle: [^\\[\\]]+]");
public static final Pattern LANGUAGE = Pattern.compile("\\[Language: [^\\[\\]]+]");
public static final Pattern CONTENTS = Pattern.compile("\\[Contents: [^\\[\\]]+]");
public static final Pattern TEMPX = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,5}$");
public static final Pattern TEMPY = Pattern.compile("^\\d{1,5}|\\d{1,5}[A-Z]?\\s?$");
public static final Pattern I = Pattern.compile("^, by ");
public static final Pattern J = Pattern.compile("\\s+(?<= )\\d+(\\w)?$|(?<= )\\d+(\\w)?\\s+$|(?<=\\D)\\d+(\\w)?$");
public static final Pattern ID = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]\\d+");
```

2) Instead of using a `for` with index, I suggest a `for-each`.

```java
for (String para : paragraphs) {
   //[...]
}
```

3) For the two sections that don't have an `else` (Title & Author), I suggest that you extract them in methods.

```java
private static void defineBooks(List<String> paragraphs) {
   //[...]
   if (mtitle.find()) {
     replaceTitle(para, book);
  }

  if (mauthor.find()) {
     replaceAuthor(mauthor, book);
  }
   //[...]
}

private static void replaceAuthor(Matcher mauthor, Book book) {
 String bauthor = I.matcher(mauthor.group()).replaceAll("");
 book.setAuthor(J.matcher(bauthor).replaceAll(""));
}

private static void replaceTitle(String para, Book book) {
 book.setTitle(para.replaceAll("\\[[^\\[]+(?:])", "")
  .replaceAll("(Passed | by|, by).*+", "")
  .replaceAll("\\s{2,}\\d{1,5}(\\s)?", "")
  .replaceAll("\n", " ")
  .replaceAll(",$", "")
  .replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim());
}
```

4) For the rest, you can make methods that return a `String` in all cases.

```java
private static void defineBooks(List<String> paragraphs) {
   //[...]
   book.setSubtitle(parseSubTitle(msubtitle, book));
   book.setContents(parseContents(mcontents));
   book.setLanguage(parseLanguage(mlanguage));
   //[...]
}
```

````java
private static String parseLanguage(Matcher mlanguage) {
 if(mlanguage.find()) {
   return mlanguage.group()
   .replaceAll("\\[Language: ", "")
   .replaceAll("]", "")
   .replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
 } else {
   return "English";
 }
}

private static String parseContents(Matcher mcontents) {
 if(mcontents.find()) {
   return mcontents.group()
   .replaceAll("\\[Contents: ", "")
   .replaceAll("]", "")
   .replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
 } else {
   return "";
 }
}

private static String parseSubTitle(Matcher msubtitle, Book book) {
 if (msubtitle.find()) {
   return msubtitle.group()
   .replaceAll("\\[Subtitle: ", "")
   .replaceAll("]", "")
   .replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
 } else {
   return "";
 }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to compile the regular expressions again and again, you can create a little helper class:

```java
public class Patterns {
    private final Map<String, Matcher> matchers = new HashMap<>();

    public Matcher compile(String pattern) {
        return matchers.computeIfAbsent(pattern, any -> Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(""));
    }

    public String replaceAll(String s, String pattern, String replacement) {
        Matcher m = compile(pattern);
        m.reset(s);
        return m.replaceAll(replacement);
    }
}
```

This class compiles the regular expressions once. It allows you to use them many times in a convenient way:

```java
Patterns pats = new Patterns();
String replaced = pats.replaceAll("text", "..", "two letters");
```

If that's still not enough, you can use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`, which (despite its name) also replaces *all* occurrences, it just operates on simple strings and since Java 9 is implemented efficiently.